# iterate all Items of MenuStrip using control access

Tags: vb.net, controls, menustrip

Hi when I try to iterate through all MenuStrip i don´t know how to iteratate
using MenuStrip  like control

here code

```
Public Sub FindAllChildren(ByRef StartingContainer As System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection)
    For Each child As Control In StartingContainer
        'MsgBox(child.Name)
        If (child.GetType() Is GetType(MenuStrip)) Then
            soonmenustrip(child.Container)
        Else
            MsgBox(child.Name)
        End If

        If child.HasChildren Then
            FindAllChildren(child.Controls)
        End If

    Next
End Sub

Public Sub soonmenustrip(ByRef StartingContainer As MenuStrip)
    For Each t As ToolStripItem In StartingContainer.Items
        MsgBox(t.Name)
    Next
End Sub
```

send me error
Error   1   'Items' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.Control'

Comment: Iterate your For/Each using  `MenuStrip` rather than Control to access MenuStrip/ToolStrip  properties

Comment: yes works this way but i can't, because is a for/each get all names content in a form in vb, and included all menu and submenus content in a Menustrip

Comment: I have no idea what that means.  If you want to access MenuStrip properties (Items) you need to iterate or cast to MenuStrip.

Comment: Plutonix: i need to get all textbox name's content in a form using dynamic way, and ass you say is not dynamic, because if you can see my code i did using control access but the problem is when try to get all ithems from a menustrip so i need to know is there are any way